# Do the Update Salesforce Object Activities in Journey Builder count towards CRM’s API limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, updaterecord, crm

When using the Marketing Cloud Connector, the documentation states that:

> “Connected App Authentication is a secure authentication mechanism
> used by Marketing Cloud Connect. It removes SOAP and REST API limits
> for Marketing Cloud Connect. Connected App Authentication does not
> lift BULK API limits. API calls made into the Marketing Cloud do not
> count against your daily limit.”

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_authentication.htm&type=5

Does this also mean that API calls made from SFMC to CRM also do not count towards the daily limit? I’m specifically referring to using the Update Salesforce Objects activity within Journey Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any "native" updates of CRM from SFMC don't count towards the limits. This applies to:

- [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject.html) function
- [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/retrievesalesforceobjects.html) function
- All the [Sales and Service Cloud Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_sales_service_cloud_activities.htm&type=5)
   in Journey Builder

However, if you are using the generic REST API for e.g. [creating new records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm), this could be from a Script Activity in Automation Studio - it will indeed count towards your daily limit.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you for confirming.